# Node.js fetch YouTube Music HTML

Tags: node.js

I will attempt to explain my problem as clear as possible while also keeping the length of this topic as short as possible. Recently, I have wanted to get the HTML of a YouTube Music song page so I can read some information off of it. Having this information in mind, I will try to split my topic into multiple sections for a clearer understanding.

#### Ultimate Goal

Since many questions can be easily solved using alternative ways, I'd like to discuss what my ultimate goal is. My ultimate goal for this project is to be able to fetch certain metadata from a selected song (Author(s), Album, Year, and Cover Photo) using Node.js. I tried messing around with the [youtube-music-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-youtube-music) library, and although it works in some scenarios, it has its flaws in cases of non-real artists (artists who's name does not redirect to a channel), as well as searching a song by ID. That being said, I wanted to be able to make a program which can fetch all of the metadata that I want from a Node.js script.

#### Actual Question

Now for the actual question. I wanted to ask how it would be possible to retrieve the HTML of a song page if I have the song URL. I tried using the following code, but it brought me to an error page:

```js
const https = require("https")

https.get("SONG URL", function(res) {
    console.log(res.statusCode);
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}).on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

[image]
To translate, it basically says that YouTube Music is not supported on the current browser.

I also tried using `axios` with the 'User-Agent' header set to Chrome, and although it didn't give me the "browser not supported" page, it did not give me the HTML that I needed. Here is the code that I used:

```js
const axios = require("axios")

async function run() {
    let res = await axios.get("SONG URL", {headers: {'User-Agent': 'Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.246', "Accept-Language": "en-US"}})
    console.log(res.data)
}

run()
```

That being said, I really do not know how I'd be able to fetch the HTML of the actual YouTube Music page. Once I am able to retrieve the HTML, I actually know what to do from there to fetch the metadata since I already made a Chrome Plugin which does that, but I need to be able to retrieve the HTML in the first place in order to be able to fetch the data from it.

If someone knows how exactly I could do this or has an alternative way, please let me know. Thank you for your time and help, I truly appreciate it.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you test this same functionality in a different browser?

Comment: @rags2riches-prog I am not using a browser, I am using a Node.js script. I just tried using axios with a chrome user-agent, and although I do not get the same "browser not supported" response, I do not get the HTML that I need.

Comment: so the first test produced a browser-related error while the second did not - this means there are browsers that aren't supported by the API. Can you include a try/catch block in your second test? let's console log the variable res inside a try statement and the error if any inside the catch statement - what is the output of this?

Comment: @rags2riches-prog I assume that the problem I come across is the fact that scripts aren't loaded. From what I can see, YouTube Music loads basic HTML and then loads up scripts which in turn finalize it so you can listen to music. I guess I'd need a way for it to wait for everything to load and then mess around with the HTML.

Comment: If I where you I would instead have a look to the JavaScript variables that contain the data to generate the HTML.